# Using multiple values in StrToMember

Tags: sql-server, tfs, ssas, mdx

I am trying to customize an SSRS report which is bundled with TFS.
The current report displays data only for **"Active"** bugs. I need to change it to display **"New"** and **"Approved"** bugs.

**Explanation:** In our environment we consider New/Approved bugs as Active bugs, and we do not use Active status.

These values need to be hard-coded, so there is no need to create parameters for these.

The current MDX query in report is as below:

```
SELECT
{
    [Measures].[Work Item Count]
} ON COLUMNS,
{
    // Filter out people who don't currently have any work items assigned to them.
    NonEmpty
    (
        CrossJoin
        (
            //
            // This block of code gets the top 10 users, based on how many active bugs they have.
            //
            TopCount(
                NonEmpty(
                    [Work Item].[System_AssignedTo].Children,
                    [Measures].[Work Item Count]
                ),
                @TopUserCount,
                [Measures].[Work Item Count]
            ),
            [Work Item].[Microsoft_VSTS_Common_Priority].[All].Children,
            [Work Item].[Microsoft_VSTS_Common_Severity].[All].Children
        ),
        [Measures].[Work Item Count]
    )
} ON ROWS
FROM
(
    SELECT
        CrossJoin(
            StrToMember("[Team Project].[Project Node GUID].&[{" + @ProjectGuid + "}]"),
            StrToMember("[Work Item].[System_WorkItemType].[" + @BugName + "]"),                   
            StrToMember("[Work Item].[System_State].&[" + @ActiveName + "]"),
            StrToSet(@AreaParam),
            StrToSet(@IterationParam),
            StrToSet(@PriorityParam),
            StrToSet(@SeverityParam)
        ) ON COLUMNS
    FROM [Team System]
```

I was suggested to change below line:

```
StrToMember("[Work Item].[System_State].[" + @ActiveName + "]"),
```

to this:

```
StrToSet("{[Work Item].[System_State].&[New],[Work Item].[System_State].&[Approved]}")
```

I tried this and it show and error while executing report:

```
An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
Query execution failed for dataset 'dsCurrentBugCountAllUsers'. (rsErrorExecutingCommand)
Query (23, 4) Parser: The syntax for 'StrToSet' is incorrect.
```

I also tried changing it to this:

```
StrToSet("{[Work Item].[System_State].[New],[Work Item].[System_State].[Approved]}")
```

and this:

```
StrToSet("{[Work Item].[System_State].[New]}")
StrToSet("{[Work Item].[System_State].&[New]}")
```

All of these gives same error as above.

Can someone advise me what I am doing wrong?

**Note: I am a complete n00b in MDX.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want **single** quotes rather than double. For example, this works against the AdventureWorks cube.

```
    SELECT StrToSet 
('{[Geography].[Geography].[Country].[Germany],[Geography].[Geography].[Country].[Canada]}')
 ON 0
    FROM [Adventure Works]
```

Comment: I created a new report parameter with 2 default values [Work Item].[System_State].&[New], [Work Item].[System_State].&[Approved]. and changed query in DataSet to **StrToSet(@NewParameterName)**. SO I guess { } are not required?

Comment: When we use a multi-value parameter from SSRS in a DataSet query, it's converted to 'Value1', 'Value2', 'Value3'. So I guess @NewParameterName is converted to: **StrToSet('[Work Item].[System_State].&[New]','[Work Item].[System_State].&[Approved]')**. Is this assumption correct?

Comment: I believe you still have to put the StrtoSet.  So in your query you would have StrToSet(@NewParameterName).  SSRS will pass {'[Work Item].[System_State].&[New]','[Work Item].[System_State].&[Approved]'}